# How to set WCF base addresses in code when using the Configure method

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

For pure code-based WCF configuration, in .NET 4.0 one could configure a base address for a service when creating an instance of a ServiceHost (assuming a self-hosted scenario, which is suitable for my needs). While one could still do this with .NET 4.5, MSDN implies that using the new `Configure()` method is a better practice because it makes such code-based configuration a bit easier for self-hosted and a lot easier for web hosted scenarios (see [Configuring WCF Services in Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205277(v=vs.110).aspx)).

The problem, however, is that though the object you have to work with inside the Configure method (a System.ServiceModel.ServiceConfiguration) has a `BaseAddresses` property it is read-only. Surely there must be a way to *set* the base addresses in code? My web searches have turned up not only nothing about this specific question, but no articles or posts about this Configure method at all, except for the single MSDN page I have referenced!

Comment: This is seriously WTF. I'm having the same issue as you now and am baffled at the lack of discussion about this online.

Answer (score 1):

Looking in reflector what `BaseAddresses` property does:

```
// System.ServiceModel.ServiceConfiguration
public ReadOnlyCollection<Uri> BaseAddresses
{
    get
    {
        return this.host.BaseAddresses;
    }
}
```

I was unable to find any other method in ServiceConfiguration working with ServiceHost.BaseAddresses

Instance of `ServiceConfiguration` is created using `ServiceHost` instance:

```
// System.ServiceModel.ServiceConfiguration
internal ServiceConfiguration(ServiceHost host)
{
    ServiceConfiguration.CheckArgument<ServiceHost>(host, "host");
    this.host = host;
}
```

This means that `ServiceConfiguration` is just an extension to standard way of configuring `ServiceHost`. So I would suggest any old way of setting `BaseAddress` is still considered as the best practice (programmatic or using configuration).